# Having clause with count not working

Tags: sql-server

I’ve written code which counts the number of Products in each Subcategory. But it only includes products with a pack size that's greater than 5.

However, I get the error message shown in the text below. Do you know why?

```
SELECT COUNT(ClientProductID), SubCategoryName
FROM v_EnterpriseStructure
GROUP BY ClientProductID
HAVING (PackSizeNum) > 5;
```

Error message:

> Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 279 Column
>   'v_EnterpriseStructure.PackSizeNum' is invalid in the HAVING clause
>   because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause.

I'd be grateful if could add the correction to the code.

Comment: Remember that the WHERE clause is used to filter individual rows and the HAVING clause is used to filter groups.

Comment: This looks like homework, but is not tagged so - from secod post of OP: "However, I need to demonstrate examples of code using the HAVING clause."

Answer (score 2):

Just omit `having` and use `where`, like:

```
SELECT COUNT(ClientProductID), SubCategoryName
FROM v_EnterpriseStructure
WHERE  PackSizeNum > 5
GROUP BY SubCategoryName
```

Comment: Should be grouping by SubCategoryName instead of ClientProductID

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me, apomene.

However, I need to demonstrate examples using the HAVING clause.

Is it still possible to do this using the HAVING clause?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(ClientProductID), SubCategoryName
FROM v_EnterpriseStructure
WHERE (PackSizeNum) > 5
GROUP BY ClientProductID, SubCategoryName;
```

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me, Milan.

However, I need to demonstrate examples using the HAVING clause.

Is it still possible to do this using the HAVING clause?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(ClientProductID), SubCategoryName
FROM v_EnterpriseStructure
GROUP BY ClientProductID, SubCategoryName Having (PackSizeNum) > 5

Comment: Thanks Milan, but I still get the same error message that I had before when I try the code you've written above? ie "Column 'v_EnterpriseStructure.PackSizeNum' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: Try this: SELECT COUNT(ClientProductID), SubCategoryName, PackSizeNum FROM v_EnterpriseStructure GROUP BY ClientProductID, SubCategoryName, PackSizeNum Having (PackSizeNum) > 5

Comment: Excellent! That worked! Thank you! I see that you simply added PackSizeNum to the fields being selected and also added it to the Group By clause! Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Hi Milan, quick question - do you always have to use 'GROUP BY' when using the HAVING clause?

Comment: Actually, I just checked and it looks like you do have to use the GROUP BY clause whenever using the HAVING clause. Thanks for clarifying the other question.

Comment: Yes, "HAVING" clause always use with GROUP BY, and the columns you select always same columns should be use in GROUP BY.

Comment: Ok, great. Thanks for letting me know.